# CakePHP 3 Debugkit.toolbar will not load

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Just setup CakePHP 3 and get this error after I added the plugin hooks to the code in the AppController and bootstrap.php

```
Error: Class 'App' not found File /var/www/fastcom-portal-one/app/plugins/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php    
Line: 16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DebugKit has not yet been updated for CakePHP 3.

Answer (score 3):

Remember to run 
`bin/cake plugin assets symlink`
So DebugKit is able to load its assets correctly.

Comment: This is the correct answer now that CakePHP 3 supposedly supports DebugKit right out of the box. For whatever reason, I had to do this on my WAMP install before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's already supported, install it using composer:

```
  "require": {
    "cakephp/debug_kit": "3.0.*-dev"
  },
```

From now on  you don't need to set DebugKit in your `AppController`, just add this to your `bootstrap.php` file:

```
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

Comment: You don't need to load your plugin in bootstrap.php file as it's already loaded there for development mode: // Only try to load DebugKit in development mode: 

// Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
// Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}